# Kolmogorv-Smirnov Test in R package(dgof) -Discrete Case

Tags: r, poisson, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have the following data,

```
Data <- c(8, 15,  8, 10,  7,  5,  2, 11,  8,  7,  6,  6,  4,  6, 10,
          3,  9,  7, 15,  6,  5,  9,  8,  3,  3,  8,  5, 14,  8, 11,
          8, 10,  7,  4,  6,  4,  6,  7, 11,  7,  8,  7,  8,  6,  5,
          12,  7,  8, 13, 10,  6,  9,  7)
```

and I want to perform a KS test in R using the `dgof` package but have no idea how to use it. I also fit the above data with binomial and Poisson distribution.

Now, I want to use KS test to identify which model (binomial or Poisson) represents the data.

Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? Did you read the help page for the function `?ks.test`? Did you try any of the examples listed on that help page? I'm not sure what your specific programming question is here. If you have questions about statistical tests, you should be asking at [stats.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you have two problems.

1. The test of kolmogorov does not apply to continuous distributions. [Kolmogorov-Smirnov Goodness-of-Fit Test](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm)
2. It has ties in the data.

even if I wanted to apply the test it would be in the following way, eliminate the duplicate values and use the maximum likelihood estimators for the poisson and binomial distributions.

```
x <- unique(Data)
ks.test(x,"ppois",lambda <- mean(x))

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.2058, p-value = 0.5273
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(x,"pbinom",n <- length(x),p <- mean(x)/n)

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.3126, p-value = 0.103
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

We could conclude that the Poisson model best represents the data, without relying on the p-value.